# xsl template match for elements that have child elements of one name or another 2 be used to delete these parent elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using xsl 1.0.
I have this xml I need to strip elements out of if they have certain children or siblings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncDMMAXINTOBJECT xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    creationDateTime="2019-09-08T15:53:31-04:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN"
                    messageID="1" maximoVersion="7 6 20181212-1733 V76010">
    <DMMAXINTOBJECTSet>
        <MAXINTOBJECT action="AddChange">
            <ALIASCONFLICT>0</ALIASCONFLICT>
            <MAXINTOBJDETAIL>
                <ALTKEY></ALTKEY>
                <OBJECTNAME>WORKORDER</OBJECTNAME>
                <MAXINTOBJCOLS>
                    <NAME>ACTCONSTCOST</NAME>
                    <OBJECTNAME>WORKORDER</OBJECTNAME>
                </MAXINTOBJCOLS>
                <MAXINTOBJCOLS>
                    <NAME>ACTCONSTCOST2</NAME>
                    <OBJECTNAME>WORKORDER</OBJECTNAME>
                </MAXINTOBJCOLS>
                <MAXINTOBJALIAS>
                    <ALIASNAME>CODEPARK</ALIASNAME>
                    <NAME>CODEPARK</NAME>
                </MAXINTOBJALIAS>
                <MAXINTOBJALIAS>
                    <ALIASNAME>CODEPARK2</ALIASNAME>
                    <NAME>CODEPARK2</NAME>
                </MAXINTOBJALIAS>
            </MAXINTOBJDETAIL>
        </MAXINTOBJECT>
    </DMMAXINTOBJECTSet>
</SyncDMMAXINTOBJECT>
```

I would like to setup a template to match all elements of the type MAXINTOBJCOLS
if they have a child element NAME with the value of ACTCONSTCOST and a child element OBJECTNAME with the value of WORKORDER, or if they have a parent element MAXINTOBJDETAIL with a child element OBJECTNAME with the value of WORKORDER, and a child element ALIASNAME with the value of CODEPARK.

So If I ran my template and it was empty it would turn the above XML into this (2 elements have been moved):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncDMMAXINTOBJECT xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    creationDateTime="2019-09-08T15:53:31-04:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN"
                    messageID="1" maximoVersion="7 6 20181212-1733 V76010">
    <DMMAXINTOBJECTSet>
        <MAXINTOBJECT action="AddChange">
            <ALIASCONFLICT>0</ALIASCONFLICT>
            <MAXINTOBJDETAIL>
                <ALTKEY></ALTKEY>
                <OBJECTNAME>WORKORDER</OBJECTNAME>
                <MAXINTOBJCOLS>
                    <NAME>ACTCONSTCOST2</NAME>
                    <OBJECTNAME>WORKORDER</OBJECTNAME>
                </MAXINTOBJCOLS>
                <MAXINTOBJALIAS>
                    <ALIASNAME>CODEPARK2</ALIASNAME>
                    <NAME>CODEPARK2</NAME>
                </MAXINTOBJALIAS>
            </MAXINTOBJDETAIL>
        </MAXINTOBJECT>
    </DMMAXINTOBJECTSet>
</SyncDMMAXINTOBJECT>
```

I am using this XSL to duplicate but I can't seem to figure out the match given the parent child element relationships -

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:max="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" exclude-result-prefixes="max">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Element[@attr1='one' and @attr2='two']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I believe I have to replace this one  with 2 others to achieve my goal:

(does nothing but proof of concept - the second one clears the changeby attribute)

```
<xsl:template match="Element[@attr1='one' and @attr2='two']"/>

<xsl:template match="max:SyncDMMAXINTOBJECT/max:DMMAXINTOBJECTSet/max:MAXINTOBJECT/max:CHANGEBY/text()"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following empty template in combination with the identity template:

```
<xsl:template match="max:MAXINTOBJCOLS[(max:NAME='ACTCONSTCOST' and max:OBJECTNAME='WORKORDER3') or (../../max:MAXINTOBJDETAIL[max:OBJECTNAME='WORKORDER' and .//max:ALIASNAME='CODEPARK'])]"/>
```

It matches both `max:MAXINTOBJCOLS` elements and removes them. The rest is copied. The `.//max:ALIASNAME` checks if `max:MAXINTOBJDETAIL` has a descendant named `max:ALIASNAME`. It does not check only for a direct child.

Comment: With minor tweaks this works great - thanks so much. I had to get back up to speed on the expressions and this was VERY helpful.